# How to specify flags in regexp?

Tags: postgresql

My `tableA` has `src_text` field of type `text`. I want to be able to specify flags in my regexp in order to properly filter my text fields, like on [this website](https://regex101.com/).

```
select *
from tableA
where tableA.src_text ~ '/Par/gms'
```

This statement literally looks for `'/Par/gms'` string while I want it to filter by `src_text` fields with `Par` text inside it, using `g`, `m` and `s` regexp flags.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: These flags do not really make sense for a simple pattern match (and some of them are contradicting, such as `m` and `s`). What are you really trying to do, and what makes you think you need flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GMB said, some flags like `g` only make sense if you are interested in the matching substrings, not if you want to test if the pattern matches or not.

You could use the function

`regexp_match(string, pattern, flags)`

which will return matching substrings. The result `IS NOT NULL` if the pattern matches.